# SQL Server - triggers don't fire for specific user

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Recently I came across a particular SQL Server user account on a server I'm working on, which can execute queries that don't cause triggers to fire. The same queries, executed under a different user, fire the triggers as expected.

I checked the sys.triggers table using the user in question and they are all enabled.

Is there a setting somewhere in SQL Server which prevents triggers from being fired for particular user accounts?

Comment: Please provide an example of the query. Certain BULK operations have flags that allow you to control if triggers should be fired.

Comment: and an example of the trigger too.

Answer (score 0):

There is not setting or knob which you can activate so that triggers wont fire for few users.You need some custom logic

This works by using a <kbd>Return</kbd> statemnt and Checking username with <kbd>[SUSER_SNAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx)</kbd>

```
create trigger trg_test2
on dbo.test2
after insert
as
Begin

if ( suser_Sname()='mike')
Begin
return
END

insert into dbo.test3
select * from inserted

end


--test2 has trigger which inserts into test3

insert into dbo.test2
select 1

select * from test2
select * from test3--Table 3 wont have any data if username is mike
```

Comment: It is possible that a user in question is executing only BULK INSERT commands. This command has a setting to disable triggers.